# difference between classification and regression in k-nearest neighbor?

Tags: machine-learning, nearest-neighbor

what is the difference between using K-nearest neighbor in classification and using it in regression?

and when using KNN in recommendation system. Does it concerned as classification or as regression?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classification tasks, the user seeks to predict a `category`, which is usually represented as an integer *label*, but represents a category of "things". For instance, you could try to classify pictures between "cat" and "dog" and use label 0 for "cat" and 1 for "dog".

The KNN algorithm for classification will look at the k nearest neighbours of the input you are trying to make a prediction on. It will then output the most frequent label among those k examples.

In regression tasks, the user wants to output a numerical value (usually continuous). It may be for instance estimate the price of a house, or give an evaluation of how good a movie is.

In this case, the KNN algorithm would collect the values associated with the k closest examples from the one you want to make a prediction on and aggregate them to output a single value. usually, you would choose the average of the k values of the neighbours, but you could choose the median or a weighted average (or actually anything that makes sense to you for the task at hand).

For your specific problem, you could use both but regression makes more sense to me in order to predict some kind of a "matching percentage ""between the user and the thing you want to recommand to him.

Comment: adding one more point to @Joseph Budin's answer:

Performance metric used to assess how good the KNN classification model is, are like- Precision, Recall etc. and with KNN Regression, performance metric that can be used are RSE, R2(R-Squared), RMSE, MSE etc...